# .htaccess URL rewrite help!

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess and mod_rewrite in my little PHP framework. It's working nicely, but I want to expand on just having it redirect everything to index.php.

My directory structure is something like this (obviously simplified)

```
apps
media
system
-- admin
jscript
templates
```

My current rewrite rules is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|jscript)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

As you can see, everything 'mydomain.com/url' is redirected to index.php. What I would like to do now is allow anything 'mydomain/admin/' to direct to the 'admin' directory inside the 'system' folder. I want normal conditions inside this folder too, so rather than use clean users, I would use urls like 'mydomain.com/admin/some-kind-of-file.php'.

In a nutshell, I just want my rewrite condition to apply to everything except my system/admin folder.

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please supply a list of 3 "from" URLs, and what they should look like after rewrite. E.g. `mydomain.com/admin/blah.php` => `mydomain.com/system/admin/blah.php` because your requirements do not appear that clear.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain it a bit better. I would like anything 'mydomain.com/admin' to look inside the 'system/admin' folder. Examples:
'mydomain.com/admin/install.php' => 'mydomain.com/system/admin/install.php'
'mydomain.com/admin/subfolder/blah.php' => 'mydomain.com/system/admin/subfolder/blah.php'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the following only applies the RewriteRule if the URL doesn't start with `site.com/index.php`, `site.com/media` or `site.com/jscript`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|jscript)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'll be honest, I hadn't seen `$1` used in a `RewriteCond` until now, but seems interesting.

So what if your url is `site.com/admin...`? Well you need a new RewriteRule. Also you need to prevent URLs beginning with `admin` get redirected by the first RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|jscript|admin|system)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^/?(admin.*)$ system/$1 [L,R]
```

*Update 1*: added `system` to the list of URLs that shouldn't be applied to the first `RewriteRule`.

*Update 2*: removing `[L,QSA]` from first `RewriteRule` and replacing with `[L,R]`.

Comment: Odd...
mydomain.com/admin/test.php
redirects to:
mydomain.com/system/admin/?install.php

Again, no idea where the ? is coming from! Perhaps there is something wrong with my apache install. I can't see why this wouldn't work!

Comment: ^/? <-- why is the ? before (admin.*) - could that be part of it?

Comment: I could be wrong about the leading slash. I'm not sure how Apache deals with it because it's part of the URL the browser requests.. I just wanted to make a leading slash optional (the `?` is a regexp operator to mean zero-or-one).

Comment: Actually why is the `[QSA]` there? I would try with `[L,R]` instead - the `[R]` means inform the browser to redirect to the new URL.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `admin` to your condition and use an additional rule to redirect it:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|jscript|admin)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/.* system/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Adding the trailing slash to the RewriteCond is a good idea, except that it will try to match "index.php/"

Answer (score 1):

It seems your 'media' and 'jscript' folders are already exempted from the rewrite rule, couldn't you just add the 'admin' folder too? eg:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|jscript|admin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you want to actually redirect everything under /admin to /system/admin (which will update the URL in the user's browser too) you'd use a mod_alias rule like this:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/admin/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/system/admin/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Nick. I'm sorry if my post wasn't clear. The admin folder is a subdirectory of the 'system' folder, meaning the above won't work. Whilst I could have system/admin as a rewrite condition, I want to actually redirect anything mydomain.com/admin to mydomain.com/system/admin

Comment: I misunderstood the question... have edited post to do what I think you're after

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the people heading to the admin folder first, then filter the rest, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)$ system/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|jscript)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried this originally, funnily enough. For some reason it doesn't work. If I type in the following:

mydomain.com/admin/

It redirects me here:

mydomain.com/system/admin/?

I have no idea where the ? is coming from!

Comment: Try this:
http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/
I've had a copy glued to my wall for the last year or so.